# Does Netty support multiple network interface cards?

Tags: netty, tap, tun

I have two questions.
Firstly, I want to start several netty process binding to different network interface card for simulation purpose, but I cannot see any information about it. So, can anyone give me an explicit reply? 
Secondly, is there any wrapper library in Java to drive tun/tap? I want to implement virtual network interface cards by using tun/tap.

Thanks very much!!!